# Dodge Dakota 2001 fluid leak under front?

Tags: dodge, water-leak, refrigerant

Dripping front that black area. It is a thin fluid, with a tan tint, no smell, not very oily/slippery. Possibly just water? Biggest thing I can think of is I got my A/C recharged a few days ago, then it gradually has been dripping out more and more. Is it my A/C has a leak and this is extra condensation runoff?

edit: I have not ran the AC consistently because it still blows out room temperature air after recharge, no cool air.

[image]

Comment: It could be water drainage form the AC.

Answer (score 0):

If you just had the A/C charged and it's still blowing warm, sounds like what you're seeing is the compressor oil leaking out. Assuming the recharge included adding new oil. Observe the A/C clutch with system and engine on, it should cycle off and on...easy to spot. If you can't see the clutch, with the engine off, feel if the A/C lines are cold.

If the A/C is functional and that's water dripping, but the cabin is still warm, look at the blend door for the heater, it might be stuck open.

It looks like you've also had the steering rack replaced? Might be a P/S line leaking, but that should have a noticeable odor and viscosity (and you'll seen hear the pump).

Comment: I have had my power steering rack replaced recently. I also checked the reservoir and the fluid seems to be the same as the leak, even though it also has no distinct smell to it.  The last time I added power steering fluid prior to the rack replacement, I remember it being a much darker color. What kind of fluid should I add into the reservoir? Seems it might be getting low.

Comment: Also should add the fluid I got was according to the manual.

Comment: Sounds like you need to bring the vehicle back to the shop that did the steering rack.  The hard lines on older systems don't like to be disturbed and it's possible you have developed a leak.  Keep the P/S fluid level topped off and make an appointment soon.  That puddle is your warning, running the rack dry will get costly.

Answer (score 0):

It will take about 10 seconds to rule out a radiator leak. Touch your finger to it then touch your tongue , sweet is antifreeze , then spit . Relax, I did not say to drink it.